# ASP.net button Jquery BlockUI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, blockui, aspbutton

I'm having trouble getting an ASP button to call a jquery script, in this case BlockUI, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddUser" Text="Add Currency Combination" ValidationGroup="valSum2" CssClass="showHide" OnClientClick="overlay"

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#overlay').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' } }); 
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
    }); 
});  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it using the css classname .ShowHide

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.showHide').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' } }); 
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
    }); 
});  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script is looking for a DOM element with ID "overlay" which does not exist. The id of the button is btnAddUser.ClientID

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddUser" Text="Add Currency Combination" ValidationGroup="valSum2" CssClass="showHide" />  

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('<%= btnAddUser.ClientID %>').click(function() {   
        $.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' } });   
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);  
    });   
});  </script>
```

Note the removal of OnClientClick!

Alternatively you can make this code a named function and type its name in the OnClientClick property. You can also bind by CssClass ( $('.showHide') ) (see @PraveenVenu's answer) but this will bind the function to all elements that use this css class.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work, do I need to do something with the .ClientID?

Comment: Ahh, the CSS approach seemed to work. It's fine as the button is the only one to use that class. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
use ()
```

you have to execute the func ...

```
 OnClientClick="overlay()"
```

Comment: There isn't a function called overlay.

Comment: @Archer I only told him to run the function with parenthesis.

Comment: But there isn't one???  It's not good advice to tell him to do something that will not work unless you explain why you're telling him.