# JQuery spinner in asp.net submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want open jQuery div spinner on asp.net submit and do some business logic and hide or close the spinner? How can I do that? I need it in regular asp.net application.

Please share me if you have samples or articles?

Comment: Please define "jQuery div spinner". Are you talking about an animated gif?

Comment: Regular POST methods, or AJAX methods (perhaps inside an `UpdatePanel`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice jquery plugin called blockui:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Here are few examples how to use it in asp.net application:

[ASP.net button Jquery BlockUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583588/asp-net-button-jquery-blockui)

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-enhance-aspnet-ajax-progress-indication/

Answer (score 0):

Hey It seems like you want to show a loader or loading gif image that should tell the user that something is happening and be patient! As such you have not specified whether you are using web forms or mvc, For web forms, you can use update progress which you can use with update panel see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18238/The-UpdateProgress-Control-of-ASP-NET-AJAX-Extensi)
If you are using mvc, with a combination of ajax in jquery way, you might want to use [ajaxstart or ajaxsetup](http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-loading-ajaxstartajaxsetup/). If you are using jquery's ajax way with web forms, you can apply the same logic with web forms too. But be specific what you are looking after!